# Best way to do one-way car rentals in the US

Tags: car-rentals

I'm looking to do a one-way car rental from JFK to PHL (pickup in New York, and drop off in Philadephia). On traditional rental sites, the cost is 10x the cost of a regular rental drop off in the same city.

Is there a way to get this cheaper?

Comment: Best? By best I assume you just mean 'cheapest'?

Comment: Can you provide some reference as to which sites you tried?

Comment: Yea, cheapest. I searched the usual Expedia, Priceline, etc for rentals.

Comment: You might be better off just taking the train(s) to Philly, and then renting a car there if needed.

Comment: Out of curiosity I tried this booking at hertz.com. From/to JFK they quoted $112.94, but from JFK to PHL it was $171.99. That's significantly more expensive but nothing like 10x. Maybe try the rental agencies directly?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get a one-way for minimal extra charge between Lubbock, TX and Dallas, TX (5+ hours drive).

I didn't have any choice on the vehicle, it was an "upgrade" to a relatively huge F150 pickup truck compared to the compact or subcompact I paid for. I didn't have any choice because that was a vehicle they wanted to have transported to Dallas, and I was volunteering to do the job for better than free (and pay for the gas too, at at least double the cost of the small car, but, hey, gas in Texas is pretty cheap anyway).

So, if you shop around to different car rental companies and perhaps play with different dates, you may be able to find such a deal.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of years ago, a five-hour one-way Hertz rental from ORD was $240, with no advance notice.  Expensive but not ten times as much.  If it had been planned, it would probably have been less.